# `registry-mirrors` with Harbor as pull-through registry cache

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to configure Harbor as a pull-through registry linked to Docker hub.

While I manage to pull images by prefixing them [per the doc](https://goharbor.io/docs/2.1.0/administration/configure-proxy-cache/), I cannot make it work by using the `registry-mirrors` Docker daemon parameter: Commands such as `docker pull mysql` still download the layers from docker.io.

**Client config**

Docker version: 20.10.8

*/etc/docker/daemon.log:*

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": ["https://harbor.example.com"]
}
```

**Harbor config**

- Harbor v2.3.1
- Installed using `docker-compose`
- In the Harbor interface:

  - Registries \ New endpoint: Created endpoint with "Docker Hub" as provider.
  - Projects \ New project: Set name to `proxy`, ticked "Proxy Cache" and selected the above endpoint.

**Test 1: Pull image with prefix:**

```
$ docker pull harbor.example.com/proxy/library/mysql
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from proxy/library/mysql
33847f680f63: Already exists 
5cb67864e624: Already exists 
1a2b594783f5: Already exists 
b30e406dd925: Already exists 
48901e306e4c: Already exists 
603d2b7147fd: Already exists 
802aa684c1c4: Already exists 
715d3c143a06: Pull complete 
6978e1b7a511: Pull complete 
f0d78b0ac1be: Pull complete 
35a94d251ed1: Pull complete 
36f75719b1a9: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:8b928a5117cf5c2238c7a09cd28c2e801ac98f91c3f8203a8938ae51f14700fd
Status: Downloaded newer image for harbor.example.com/proxy/library/mysql:latest
harbor.example.com/proxy/library/mysql:latest
```

The second last line shows this is pulled from my repo as expected.

**Test 2: Pull image without prefix:**

```
$ docker pull mysql
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/mysql
33847f680f63: Already exists 
5cb67864e624: Already exists 
1a2b594783f5: Already exists 
b30e406dd925: Already exists 
48901e306e4c: Already exists 
603d2b7147fd: Already exists 
802aa684c1c4: Already exists 
715d3c143a06: Pull complete 
6978e1b7a511: Pull complete 
f0d78b0ac1be: Pull complete 
35a94d251ed1: Pull complete 
36f75719b1a9: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:8b928a5117cf5c2238c7a09cd28c2e801ac98f91c3f8203a8938ae51f14700fd
Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql:latest
docker.io/library/mysql:latest
```

This comes from docker.io instead of taking it from my registry! After the command above, I also see this line in /var/log/syslog:

```
Aug 11 15:54:57 myhost dockerd[12663]: time="2021-08-11T15:54:57.229516951+02:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: unknown: repository library/mysql not found"
```

Since this suggests Docker tried my registry first, I suspect the problem is in the configuration of the registry and not in Docker. Perhaps in the path conventions used by Harbor...

Has anyone managed to pull images from a Harbor cache without having to manually prefix them?